# Parsec - parse pair with a separator

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am learning Parsec and I want to acomplish a simple task, to parse a string like `"fo o--bar"` to `("fo o", "bar")` using Parsec.

I am trying:

```
parsePair :: Parser (String, String)
parsePair = do
  a <- manyTill anyChar $ string "--"
  b <- many1 alphaNum
  pure (a, b)
```

which compiles, but then `parse parsePair "" "fo o--bar"` always produces a parse error. Why is that?

Comment: What error are you receiving? [It worked inside GHCi for me](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/62046eb6a24d4c4f5bc0103f83317e40)

Comment: I get `Right ("fo o","bar")` as a result in ghci...

Comment: In the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:manyTill) there's a note at the bottom which indicates you should use `try (string "--")`

Comment: It's unclear why you've written your parser using `manyTill anyChar $ string "--"`, but that parser will cause you lots of trouble. Any parser which requires backtracking at some point is not a good parser; unless the grammar you are trying to parse is ambiguous (but you've not stated what that is).